# How can I get the information inside a Windows PE file that is displayed in the Version Tab?

Tags: windows, operating-system

I decoded the optional header and didn't really know where to go from there. It has an internal name, a version, the company name, lots of info. Where do I go to find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the [Version Information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646981.aspx) in the resources.  That documentation describes the APIs you can use to get it.

Comment: I am making a library that is not part of windows so I cannot use the API but thanks for the pointer, that it is in the resources.

Comment: There is a python package available that can do this for you :

http://pefile.googlecode.com/files/pefile-1.2.10-63.tar.gz

You can examine it to see how the PE file format is structured if you want to do it in your own language.